# How to understand Preskill's argument for degeneration of eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

In his [notes on topological quantum computation](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/topological.pdf) on page 18, Preskill uses the "commutator"
$T_2^{-1}T_1^{-1}T_2T_1 = e^{-2 i \vartheta}$ to show that the eigenstates of $T_1$ are degenerate. But I don't understand his argument, which goes as follows:

- Take an eigenstate $T_1|\alpha\rangle = e^{i \alpha}|\alpha\rangle$ of $T_1$
- Evaluate: $T_1(T_2|\alpha\rangle) = e^{i2\vartheta}e^{i\alpha}T_2|\alpha\rangle$, interpret this as $T_2$ advancing the value of $\alpha$ by $2\vartheta$
- Now suppose $\vartheta$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$, e.g. $\vartheta = \pi \frac{p}{q}$ where $p<2q$ and $(p,q)=1$
- Then he concludes that $T_1$ must have at least $q$ distinct eigenvalues, and $T_1$ acting on $\alpha$ generates an orbit with $q$ distinct values
  $$\alpha_k \equiv \alpha + \left(2\pi \frac{p}{q}\right) k\quad (\textsf{mod }2\pi) $$

My questions:

1. In the second step, does he mean something like $T_2|\alpha\rangle = |(\alpha + 2\vartheta)\textsf{mod }2\pi\rangle$, i.e. that applying $T_2$ to $|\alpha\rangle$ gives us the eigenstate $|\alpha + 2\vartheta\rangle$ of $T_1$?
2. In the fourth step, how do we conclude this? And how exactly does $T_1$ generate said orbit? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Basically yes, up to your inaccurate articles. When you say "gives us the eigenstate $|\alpha+2\vartheta\rangle$", the word "the" indicates that you believe that the eigenstate with this eigenvalue has to be unique. But you haven't proven so and it doesn't have to be the case in general. So you wanted to say "an eigenstate with the eigenvalue that would be represented by the phase $\alpha+2\vartheta$".
2. The relevant states that are said to exist in the fourth step are simply states $(T_2)^j |\alpha\rangle$ where $j=0,1,2,\dots q-1$. All these $q$ states have to be nonzero and distinct from each other because they have different eigenvalues of the normal operator $T_1$. But once you pick $j=q$, you may get the same state as for $j=0$ up to an overall normalization (phase), the states may be periodic in $j$ with the periodicity $q$.

Comment: Ok, great. But as for 2: Doesn't $T_2$ generate the orbit? I'm a bit unable to think right now

Comment: Yes, $T_2$ generates the orbit. $T_1$ is whose eigenvalues you measure, $T_2$ is what changes the eigenvalues of $T_1$. $T_2$ is like the raising ladder operator in the harmonic oscillator, except that you're only guaranteed to get new vectors a finite number of times. The verb "generate" does mean that you're supposed to act with $T_2$ repeatedly - I wrote it using the power $j$-th of $T_2$.

Comment: Yes, I got that -  so there's an error in Preskill's notes, I presume? But one thing: All these states also have distinct eigenvalues, namely $\alpha +2\pi\frac{p}{q}\cdot j$, so how exactly does this imply degeneracy?

Comment: I think it is a typo, there should be $T_2$ before "acting".

Comment: The degeneracy (of the ground state level, i.e. eigenstates of the Hamiltonian) just means that you have found several distinct - linearly independent - states that have the same eigenvalue of $H$. All the states with different eigenvalues of $T_1$ have the same eigenvalue of $H$ because $H$ commutes with $T_1$ by an assumption on a previous page. Also, $H$ commutes with $T_2$. The claim is not that the eigenstates of both $H$ and $T_1$ are degenerate. All the states found by the action of powers of $T_2$ are enough for degeneracy of $H$ levels.